# Where can I find the limitations of SQL Express in SQL Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a PC which I'm not sure whether the SQL Server installed is either the Express Version or the Full Version. I am aware that the express editions have limitation og 1GB Ram, 4GB Hard DIsk and etc.

Where can I find this information in SQL Management Studio?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Not sure what you're talking about. I've always replied to all answers.

Comment: Oh.. didn't know that was important. But I did thanked in all replies and commented them. Will do that next time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go to Help|About in Management Studio, it may tell you whether you have the Express edition of Management Studio. Another way to tell is the amount of items you have under Object Explorer - for example the Express Edition of Management Studio does not have a SQL Server Agent node at the top level under a server.

Management Studio can't tell you what version the engine is without running a query against the instance you're talking about (since you can use the same copy of Management Studio to connect to many different local and remote instances). Connect to the instance and run this query:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Edition');
```

If you can't figure out how to connect to the instance, go to Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services and tell us what you see under SQL Server or MSSQL.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do it:

```
select @@VERSION
```

Comment: That will give you the version you're running, MSDN can tell you the limitations:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx